# Trigger actionListener with partialSubmit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="labelValueContainer" columnClasses="one,two">
    <p:outputLabel value="Value" />
    <p:inputText id="englishValue" styleClass="englishValue" value="#{labelsManager.addLabelsBean.engValue}" />
</h:panelGrid>
<p:commandButton value="COPY" styleClass="copyButton" process="englishValue" partialSubmit="true" actionListener="#{labelsManager.setValueForCopy}">
```

What I'm trying to do is to submit only one inputText and trigger an actionLister (or an action) with ajax. If I remove `partialSubmit="true"`  the method "setValueForCopy" is trigger but when I add again actionListener is not triggered anymore and I don't know way.
If anyone have a better solution for submiting an input and trigger a method I'm ready to listen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `partialSubmit="true"`, only things in `process="..."` will be submitted (and processed). This is missing the `<p:commandButton>` itself.

Add it via `@this`:

```
<p:commandButton ... process="@this englishValue" partialSubmit="true" ... />
```

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces/)